# Redefine abstract method as static method and call it from base class

Tags: python, static, abstract-class, static-methods

Suppose I need to implement an abstract Python interface which then will have many derived classes (each named equally but written in different modules), and in base class I heed to have a common method which will use a particular imported derived class' static method.

So my toy modules look like this:

**abstract_class.py**

```
 from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

 from derived_class import Derived

 class Abstract:
   __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

   @abstractmethod
   def foo(self):
     pass

   def bar(self):
     Derived.foo()
```

**derived_class.py**

```
from abstract_class import Abstract

class Derived(Abstract):
  @staticmethod
  def foo():
    print 'Good news everyone!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  derived_object = Derived()
  derived_object.bar()
```

Then of course when I'm trying to run `derived_class.py`, I get the Abstract name import error.

How do I properly organize this?

Comment: Why don't you make `Abstract.bar` just call `self.foo`?

Comment: I have a feeling you might be in an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But regardless, you shouldn't use [circular imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python), even though no real danger will come of it. Also - You might want to look at [Python Super and Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: @jonrsharpe because it will call Abstract.foo, which doesn't print anything

Comment: Not in `derived_object`, it won't, because then `self` is the `Derived` instance and `foo` is the `@staticmethod`, not the `@abstractmethod`. Try it and see!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just tried it, so  `def bar(self): self.foo()`, and if I call bar() from the derived class it does not print anything

Comment: Be aware that, when running your `derived_class.py`, `'main' != '__main__'`. Using `self.foo` in `Abstract` works fine here for me; I see `Good news everyone!` as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep! It was my stupid mistake with 'main' that bothered, and your solution works just fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, if you absolutely needed to do this without an object instance, it's possible to do with classmethods rather than staticmethods.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(label: str):
        raise NotImplementedError()


    @classmethod
    def foo_agnostic(cls, label: str):
        """
        NOTE: Here, this method doesn't have a reference to an instance of the class.
        Instead, it only has a reference to the class itself; but that is enough
        to call the abstract static foo() method.
        """
        cls.foo(label)


class MyDerivedClass(MyAbstractClass):

    @staticmethod
    def foo(label: str):
        print(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = MyDerivedClass()
    instance.foo("Test 1")                # Outputs "Test 1"
    instance.foo_agnostic("Test 2")       # Outputs "Test 2"
    MyDerivedClass.foo_agnostic("Test 3") # Outputs "Test 3"
```

Comment: Maybe should `@abstractmethod` comes before `@staticmethod`?

Comment: Well, nope. I will add an answer.

Comment: @mika: The code works as advertised. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, or I won't find my comment misleading!! I meant that my first comment is 'nope', i.e. @abstractmethod should come at the second. Then I forgot to add an answer to warn that, haha.

Comment: @user26742873: Ah, OK, cool. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Just read in the profile that u are a linguist - I am currently majoring linguistics, what a coincidence. I planned to be a researcher in a university after finishing master and ph.d., and it's so glad to meet you here! I've been on Stackoverflow for several but haven't met one before.

Answer (score 0):

> ... in base class I heed to have a common method which will use a
>   particular imported derived class' static method

If I understand your question correctly, I'd say that this functionality is available out of the box with one small exception: Don't use a static method; just use a regular instance method.

Defining an abstract method in the base class will ensure that derived classes contain an implementation for that method. And, out of the box, the method defined in the derived class will get called when you call `derived_object.bar()`.